# Least Common Multiple and exponential constant $e$

Tags: limits, elementary-number-theory, least-common-multiple

$$S(n)=S(n-1)+\operatorname{lcm}[n,S(n-1)]-1$$

Given the initial $S(1)=1$.

Where
$n\ge2$ and $\operatorname{lcm}$ is the [Least Common Multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)

As an example the $\operatorname{lcm}(6,8)=24$.

Let $n:=2,3,4$ and $5$ as an example to see the sequence terms
$$S(n)=S(n-1)+\operatorname{lcm}[n,S(n-1)]-1$$
$$S(1)=1$$

---

$$S(2)=s(1)+\operatorname{lcm}[2,S(1)]-1=1+\operatorname{lcm}(2,1)-1=1+2-1=2$$
$S(2)=2$

$$S(3)=s(2)+\operatorname{lcm}[3,S(2)]-1=2+\operatorname{lcm}(3,2)-1=2+6-1=7$$
$S(3)=7$

$$S(4)=S(3)+\operatorname{lcm}[4,S(3)]-1=7+\operatorname{lcm}(4,7)-1=7+28-1=34$$
$S(4)=34$

$$S(5)=s(4)+\operatorname{lcm}[5,S(4)]-1=34+\operatorname{lcm}(5,34)-1=34+170-1=203$$
$S(5)=203$

We think the limit will hold, but how to shows it, is a hard part we can't do.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{s(n)\over (n+1)!}=3-e$$

$${2\over 3!}\approx. 0.333$$

$${7\over 4!}\approx. 0.2916$$

$${34\over 5!}\approx. 0.283$$

$${203\over 6!}\approx. 0.2819$$

$$3-e=0.28171817...$$

Does this limit hold as $n \to\infty?$

Comment: Show by induction that $S(n) = (n+1)\cdot S(n-1) - 1$.